# rule to remove items from Shopping cart

Tags: rules, commerce

I am having difficulty creating a rule to completely remove items from a Shopping cart.
I have tried Before adding a product to the cart

```
{ "rules_prevent_salon_professional_xover" : {
    "LABEL" : "Prevent Salon professional xover",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "WEIGHT" : "-18",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "staffmy" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_order", "commerce_cart" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_cart_product_prepare" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "commerce-product" ],
          "op" : "IN",
          "value" : { "value" : [ "97", "98", "99", "100" ] }
        }
      },
      { "AND" : [] },
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-user:roles:5" ], "value" : "5" } },
      { "AND" : [
          { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-user:roles:0" ], "value" : "1" } },
          { "OR" : [] },
          { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-user:roles:4" ], "value" : "4" } }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_order_update_state" : { "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ], "order_state" : "canceled" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

as well as After adding a product to the cart

```
{ "rules_prevent_professional_subscription_purchase_cross_over" : {
    "LABEL" : "Prevent Salon professional subscription purchase cross-over",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "WEIGHT" : "-18",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "staffmy" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "inline_conditions", "rules", "commerce_order", "commerce_cart" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_cart_product_add" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "commerce_product_contains_products" : {
          "commerce_line_item" : [ "commerce_line_item" ],
          "sku" : "salon-owner-monthly , salon-owner-3month , salon-owner-6month, salon-owner-yearly "
        }
      },
      { "AND" : [] },
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-user:roles:5" ], "value" : "5" } },
      { "AND" : [
          { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-user:roles:0" ], "value" : "1" } },
          { "OR" : [] },
          { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-user:roles:4" ], "value" : "4" } }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-unit-price:amount" ] } },
      { "commerce_order_update_state" : { "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ], "order_state" : "canceled" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried modifying it, by Removing entity - but still have a product in the Shopping cart

```
{ "rules_prevent_salon_professional_xover" : {
    "LABEL" : "Prevent Salon professional xover",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "WEIGHT" : "-10",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "staffmy" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_order", "commerce_cart" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_cart_product_prepare" : [], "commerce_cart_product_add" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "commerce-product" ],
          "op" : "IN",
          "value" : { "value" : [ "97", "98", "99", "100" ] }
        }
      },
      { "AND" : [] },
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-user:roles:5" ], "value" : "5" } },
      { "AND" : [
          { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-user:roles:0" ], "value" : "1" } },
          { "OR" : [] },
          { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-user:roles:4" ], "value" : "4" } }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_order_update_state" : { "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ], "order_state" : "canceled" } },
      { "entity_delete" : { "data" : [ "site:current-cart-order" ] } }
    ]
  }
}
```

This Rule does prevent the role from being added to the user, but the product and its normal product price exists in Shopping cart on the Orders page.

Comment: I think you can call the function commerce_cart_order_empty($order). It will remove all the items from cart.

Comment: Thanks Raj - unfortunately, this did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a rule that empty cart before adding any new item. So the only latest item will be in the cart. I think thats what you need to do. Any other conditions can be added one by one.

If you want to clear cart totally then you can use `after adding product event`

```
{ "rules_empty_cart_" : {
    "LABEL" : "Empty cart ",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_cart", "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_cart_product_prepare" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_cart_empty" : { "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ] } },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Cart empty event executed.!!" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks Raj. This does work and apparently my logic before this Action does not work properly.